Armstrong's definition of the boundary of the surface
On page 116 of Armstrong's Basic Topology, the definition of the boundary of the surface is: $x$ belongs to the boundary $\Leftrightarrow $ there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ and a homeomorphism $f:E^2_+ \to U $ such that $f(0) = x$. Also, he indicates that the surface is the union of its interior and boundary.
My question: If there exists a neighborhood $V$ of $x$ and a homeomorphism $g:E^2_+ \to V $, then why there must exist a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ and a homeomorphism $f:E^2_+ \to U $ such that $f(0) = x$?
Attempt: I tried to get $f$ by composite $g$ with $h$, where $h: E^2_+ \to E^2_+$ given by $(x,y) \mapsto (x+a, y+b)$ (I want to translate $g^{-1}(x)$ to the origin). But here $h$ is not onto, so it fails to be a homeomorphism.
Then what's the way to get $f$ ? Any help would be highly appreciated!

It is important to note that if $g^{-1}(x)$ has positive "$y$-coordinate" i.e. does not lie on the boundary of $E^2_+$ then in fact $x$ is an interior point! So any other $g$ would necessarily have $g(a,0)=x$ for some $a$ and then $h:(x,y)\mapsto (x+a,y)$ really is an autohomeomorphism of the closed upper half plane.

If g^{-1}(x) has positive y-coordinate, say a, then the set of all the points with y-coordinate larger than a/2 is homeomorphic to E^2, so we can choose its image under g as a neighborhood of x and deduce x is a interior. Thanks for your help!

@leo That's right, and you're welcome!
